# How C# collection initializer works?

Tags: c#

i try to find docs explaing how collection C# initializer work.
I write example, where with extension method `Add` i was initialize dictionary with other dictionary and any other object.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new()
        {
            new object(),
            new Dictionary<string, string>(),
            {"3", "3"}
        };
    }
}
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void Add<TKey,TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey,TValue> o, object obj)
    {
        //do something
    }
    public static void Add<TKey,TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey,TValue> o, Dictionary<TKey,TValue> dictionary)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: [English](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers) + [Russian](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers)

Comment: If you're asking how it works under the hood: the compiler understands what you're doing, and converts it into equivalent method calls. So `var myList = new List<int>() { 1 }` becomes something like `List<int> myList = new List<int>(); List<int>(); myList.Add(1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it's just syntax sugar. [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers) :

> Collection initializers let you specify one or more element
> initializers when you initialize a collection type that implements
> IEnumerable and has Add with the appropriate signature as an instance
> method or an extension method.

If you check the compiled code, it's just calling `Add` as you would write on your own.